# JAVA-EE Tomcat Axis2 - Setup & Project Build

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

**Hello Folks,**

**I am very new to JAVA WebService development in Eclipse environment.**

***I am using Eclipse IDE - Tomcat v7.0 Webserver - Axis2 for development.***
*Everything seems to be configured fine, since every time I start the server and visit the localhost it takes me to the Tomcat server page. And when I visit the*

> localhost:8080/axis2/

*It takes me to the Axis2 page.* **So, I think configuration has been done properly for the dev. environment.**

***Question:***

> *How does an .aar file get created so I can deploy it to a remote server? Do we create it manually or is it created when we build our
>   project?  I want to make some changes to the skeleton.java class -
>   generate the .aar file & deploy to the linux machine.*

***What I have tried:***

> *I have made desired changes to the code, built the project but I do not think there is any changes to the .aar file.*

**Any helps with this will be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here[1] once you created  SimpleService.aar file you could use Axis2 console on Tomcat to upload and deploy SimpleService.aar  file.

[1] - http://wso2.org/library/95

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to install Axis2 as a web application ad create aar next. I usually prefer a total web application which is inclued axis2 and then export it as WAR and deploy that WAR.

If you already write your web service and you can test it in eclipse, you could export it as WAR and deploy.